# GroupBy field with and without white spaces

Tags: collections, groovy

I have these invoices listed:

```
def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,']
```

I am trying to do `groupBy` on the above collection with `INVOICE_NUMBER` and trying to achieve map with `INVOICE_NUMBER` and lines as values:

```
def lines = invoices*.split('\\|').findAll{ it.size()>1 }
def heads = lines.first()
def invoiceMap =  lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
```

If I print `invoiceMap` I get what I intended as this map:

```
 [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22], 
                   [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24]], 
  INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26], 
                   [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]]
  ]
```

But if the `INVOICE_NUMBER` has any white spaces with it in the `invoices` map my code doesn't work, so I tweaked the code as below to get it working:

```
 def invLineDetails = lines.tail().collect{ [heads, it].transpose().collectEntries() }.groupBy{it[it.keySet().find{it.contains('INVOICE_NUMBER')}] }
```

Can this code be optimized/refactored further?

Answer (score 1):

I could not produce an error when an invoice number contains white spaces. I made some minor tweaks.

```
def invoices = [
'LEDES98BI V2',
'LINE|INVOICE_DATE|INVOICE_NUMBER|INVOICE_TOTAL',
'1|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|22',
'2|20150301|INV-Error_Test1|24',
'3|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|26',
'4|20150301|INV-Error_Test2|28,',
'5|20150301|INV WITH WHITESPACE|29,']


def lines = invoices
    .findAll { it.contains('|') }
    .collect { it.tokenize('|') }

def headers = lines.first()
def invoiceMap =  lines.tail().collect{
    [headers, it].transpose().collectEntries()
}.groupBy{ it.INVOICE_NUMBER }
```